# What is the difference between a "book" and a "tome"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, definition

Can anybody tell me if there is a difference in meaning and/or usage of "a book" vs "a tome"?

So far, I found on the internet that:

- **a book** is a general, versatile term
- **a tome** is an unusually thick book

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: _Tome_ in modern usage often connotes mild sarcasm in reference to a very long or challenging book: _Our professor assigned one of Malinowski's **tomes** for reading in our anthro course._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Tome (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tome)***  is an old term which is used to indicate a large, heavy book:

> - 1510s, "a single volume of a multi-volume work," from Middle French tome (16c.), from Latin tomus. ***Sense of "a large book" is attested from 1570s.***

(Etymonline)

Comment: So the Lord of the Rings 3 volumes printed as one book, would be considered a tome by this definition? That's the only book I can think of that is 1 book, usually published as 3 volumes. This definition seems a bit hyper-specific.

Answer (score 1):

As [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tome) tells us, a tome may be:

1. A large or scholarly book.
2. A volume forming part of a larger work.

Thus *tome* is a hyponim of *book*. 
However, now *tome* mostly means just a very thick book, perhaps with an ironical connotation.